# Anyway of creating very thin border lines around more cells

Tags: php, html, css

Can anyone tell me how to make border lines around more tds that have same value?

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>103</td>
      <td>103</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you edit your question more clear ?

Comment: A. You will need JavaScript for this. 2) You aren't really asking a question so much as asking people to solve your problem for you which isn't going to get you much traction.

Comment: Plz ...How do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//NOTE: if you want "Text" to have borders with "text", remove all "//" in front of ".toLowerCase()"

tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
tdsL = tds.length;

for (i = 0; i < tdsL; i++) {
  td = tds[i];

  val = td.innerHTML//.toLowerCase();
  // if this is the last element, nextVal = 7, (a number that will != a string), else nextVal = the next element's innerHTML
  nextVal = i + 1 == tdsL ? 7 : td.nextElementSibling.innerHTML//.toLowerCase();
  // if this is the first element, prevVal = 7, (a number that will != a string), else prevVal = the previous element's innerHTML
  prevVal = i == 0 ? 7 :  td.previousElementSibling.innerHTML//.toLowerCase();

  if (prevVal == val && val == nextVal) {
    td.className += " same prev-side next-side";
  } else if (prevVal == val && val !== nextVal) {
    td.className += " same prev-side";
  } else if (prevVal !== val && val == nextVal) {
    td.className += " same next-side";
  }

}
```

```css
.same {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.next-side {
  border-right: none;
}

.prev-side {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
   <tr>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>103</td>
      <td>103</td>
      <td>104</td>
      <td>105</td>
      <td>105</td>
      <td>105</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Would this code work for you?

jQuery Version

```js
(function($) {
  
  $("td").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    val = $this.text();
    nextVal = $this.next().text();
    prevVal = $this.prev().text()
    
    if (val == nextVal) {
      $this.next().addBack().addClass("same")
    }
    
    if (prevVal == val && val == nextVal) {
      $this.addClass("prev-side next-side");
    } else if (prevVal == val && val !== nextVal) {
      $this.addClass("prev-side");
    } else if (prevVal !== val && val == nextVal) {
      $this.addClass("next-side");
    }
      
    
  });
  
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.same {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.next-side {
  border-right: none;
}
.prev-side {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>102</td>
    <td>103</td>
    <td>103</td>
    <td>104</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>105</td>
    <td>105</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the same class name whose td's values are the same

```
.class {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css just make set something like

```
td {
border-width: 15px;
border-color: #000;
}
```

td is just the identifier for the cell, border-width is the thickness of the border color is the color ...

Answer (score 0):

please make your question more clear, but for table ,you can add a border with size that u what ,like this :

`

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>103</td>
      <td>103</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

`

and also , u what a specific cell to be bordered ,can be like this:

`

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td style="border:2px solid black;">102</td>
      <td>103</td>
      <td>103</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

write the same class name which tds have same value then take the class name and write css like:-